# TortoiseSVN : Error running context: The server unexpectedly closed the connection when trying to create a branch/tag

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am trying to create a branch/tag from TortoiseSVN. After I click on OK, it transfers 0 Bytes/second and it takes around 15 mins and then comes back with an error

```
"Copy C:\MyRepository to https://example.com/svn/svn_repository/tags/release_1.0, Revision HEAD"
"Error running context: The server unexpectedly closed the connection"
"Completed"
```

SVN version : 1.8.8, TortoiseSVN version : 1.9.4, SVN is setup with apache

I am able to SVN commit and update and do everything else in the repository except creating a release using branch/tag option.

apache error log :

```
[Fri Jun 09 06:58:37.301131 2017] [access_compat:error] [pid 29848] [client my_ip:61199] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: svn:path_to_my_repository_in_server

[Fri Jun 09 06:59:08.220708 2017] [access_compat:error] [pid 3480] [client my_ip:61375] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: svn:path_to_my_repository_in_server/tags/release_1.0
```

Can anyone please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue solved. The problem was not with the repository configuration but the way I created the branch/tag for the repository. There was a .svn folder inside the folder I was trying to create a branch/tag of and it was refusing the connection. But once I went inside that folder and had my .svn file outside it was able to create the branch/tag.

Answer (score -1):

@Supersonic it looks like you don't have permission to create branch/tag on SVN, you just have read/write access on that branch/trunk.talk to your SVN administrator, ask to check SVN apache configuration.

Comment: If I have Read/Write access on the branch/trunk should I not be having access to tags? I can paste the svn apace config file if you want

Comment: Not necessary. it depends how access permissions are setup in apache. you might be having permission on specific branch/trunk not on branches/tags. yeah you can share apache config.

Comment: issue has been created for creating branch. there is no chance, user has no priviliges.